# Use async API call inside loop in computed property with vue-async-computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, computed-properties

I have a computed property inside a Vue component that looks like so:

```
allUsers() {
  const vm = this;
  const users = this.getAll.map((item) => {
    let newUser = {};
    if (typeof item !== 'object') {
      newUser = {
        id: vm.userModel.id,
        userId: vm.userModel.userId,
        data: null,
        tenantData: null,
      };
    } else {
      newUser = item;
    }
    return newUser;
  });
  return users;
},
```

I need to insert some additional data into each `newUser` object, but getting that data requires 1) looping through another set of data for each `newUser` item and 2) getting the data returned from an axios call to a REST API endpoint:

```
async delete({ device, personId }) {
    return await super.perform(axios.delete(ServiceUrlProvider.gmiUrl()
      .concat('/person/')
      .concat(personId)
      .concat('/device/')
      .concat(device.deviceId)));
  }
```

Ideally I would be able to do something like this:

```
allUsers() {
  const vm = this;
  const users = this.getAll.map((item) => {
    let newUser = {};
    if (typeof item !== 'object') {
      newUser = {
        id: vm.userModel.id,
        userId: vm.userModel.userId,
        data: null,
        tenantData: null,
      };
    } else {
      newUser = item;
    }
    this.tenantApps.forEach((app) => {
      userDeviceService.fetchPersonAppDevice({
        id: item.id,
        appCode: app.code,
      })
        .then((resp) => {
          // Code here to add returned value to newUser object.
        });
    });

    return newUser;
  });
  return users;
},
```

but since it is [bad practice](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/no-async-in-computed-properties.md) to allow async actions in computed properties, I have to try something else. Based on what I found, I'm trying [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed), and I've moved my method to the separate `asyncComputed` object:

```
  asyncComputed: {
    allUsers() {
      const vm = this;
      const users = this.getAll.map((item) => {
        let newUser = {};
        if (typeof item !== 'object') {
          newUser = {
            id: vm.userModel.id,
            userId: vm.userModel.userId,
            data: null,
            tenantData: null,
          };
        } else {
          newUser = item;
        }

        this.tenantApps.forEach((app) => {
          userDeviceService.fetchPersonAppDevice({
            id: item.id,
            appCode: app.code,
          })
            .then((resp) => {
              if (Array.isArray(resp.data) && resp.data.length > 0) {
                newUser.hasDevice = true;
              } else {
                newUser.hasDevice = false;
              }
            });
        });

        return newUser;
      });
      return users;
    },
  },
```

My problem is getting `allUsers()` to wait for the returned call to `userDeviceService.fetchPersonAppDevice()`, since as it is now, it finishes and returns without waiting. I can't just use `await` on the `forEach` loop. How do I need to implement that call so that I can add the returned data to my `newUser` object?

**UPDATE:** Per comment by Estus Flask below, I've modified my `allUsers` computed value like so:

```
asyncComputed: {
  async allUsers() {
    const vm = this;
    const users = this.getAll.map((item) => {
      let newUser = {};
      if (typeof item !== 'object') {
        newUser = {
          id: vm.userModel.id,
          userId: vm.userModel.userId,
          data: null,
          tenantData: null,
        };
      } else {
        newUser = item;
      }
      const devicePromises = [];
        this.tenantApps.forEach((app) => {
          devicePromises.push(userDeviceService.fetchPersonAppDevice({
            id: item.id,
            appCode: app.code,
          }));
        });
        const devices = await Promise.all(devicePromises);
      return newUser;
    });
    return users;
  },
},
```

However, I get an error on the `await Promise.all(devicePromises);` call saying that `the await operator can only be used in an async function`. I've changed `allUsers` to be asynchronous, so why the error?

Comment: As I understand, the point of vue-async-computed is that it can chain a promise that a function returns. If it doesn't, there's nothing to wait and nothing to compute from. *I can't just use await on the forEach loop* - this is a problem to start with. Don't use forEach, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop . Make allUsers a proper `async` function that returns only when all asynchronous processes inside of it are completed.

Comment: Thanks, @EstusFlask. Any chance you could give me a code sample in an answer? I can give you credit that way, too.

Comment: @EstusFlask, you say ` Make allUsers a proper async function`, but since computed properties can't be asynchronous, do you mean just have `allUsers()` be a separate function called by the computed property?

Comment: It should be a proper `async` function in order to be used with vue-async-computed, i.e. return a promise of entire asynchronous operation.  I'd suggest to check the question I linked above and try to rewrite it. `allUsers` should be made `async`,  `forEach` should be replaced with `for..of` or `Promise.all`+`map`, `then` can be replaced with `await` because this is what async/await is for.